# understanding grails deadlock within transaction inside a loop

Tags: hibernate, grails, deadlock, database-deadlocks

currently having a transaction deadlock on a transaction inside a loop:

```
def method() {
    attemptIds.each { attemptId ->
        Attempt.withTransaction {
            def attempt = Attempt.findById(attemptId, [lock:true])
            attempt.refresh()
            //modify attempt and save
        }
    }
}
```

This method is in a non transactional service. And the method is being called concurrently. The attemptId on the list might be repeated/ not unique in the attemptIds.

So processing of the attempts should be blocking to other threads that is processing the same attempt.

We enclosed the transaction inside the loop thinking that it will commit the transaction right away, letting the other threads update the previously locked attempts.

Logs indicate that, the findBy query is being blocked by another query and vice versa, Im not sure how that is possible.

Why do you think the deadlock is occurring?

Comment: Why do you refresh after doing the find?

Comment: This most likely is going to be related to the isolation level for your database in your `Datasource.groovy`. What database engine/server are you using, what is the default is isolation level for your database, and what have you defined (even if you haven't) in your `Datasource.groovy`?

Comment: @Deigote Since the attempts are modified concurrently, we just need to make sure that the current transaction's copy is not stale.

Comment: A transaction's purpose is isolating the "database state" during its execution. Their aim is to make the result of many concurrent transactions look like if they had been executed sequencially (in any possible order). What's the point on using them if you want exactly the opposite?

Comment: @Deigote Not trying to do the opposite. I just ommitted other code above the transaction that does query attempts as well. Since hibernate caches that, there is a chance that it might not be updated anymore after the find and lock statement.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore We use postgres, and the iso level is TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED

Comment: Can the service method put the attempt IDs into a queue and then have a background task process the queue?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa the method itself is already in a queue listener processor. But that processor needs to be multithreaded to speed things up

Comment: Can you elaborate on your example to show the queuing? It seems that a gpars DataFlow might do the trick.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?